# Problem with osm2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm having a problem importing a .pbf file in PostgreSQL using the osm2pgsql.
I've downloaded the italy-latest.osm.pbf and as I do every year I'm going to upload it in PostgreSQL.
I did it for other country files and all worked well, but when I try with this one the process starts and after 4 hours after having read all nodes, ways and relations it simply stops.

I tried with the -C option augmenting the cache size, but nothing change.
Now they are 3 days I'm trying but I'm not an expert in these kinds of things.

Do you know if there is a more frindly way to import these data in Windows?

Comment: do you get any error message?

Comment: No! Any error message. It simply shows E:\users\myName >>_

Comment: You forgot to mention the osm2pgsql version you're using.

Comment: does the import work with a smaller OSM  extract?
Maybe the extract of Italy has become too large in the meanwhile ...

Comment: The version is 0.85 and with the smaller ones worked well.